# в WPF есть кнопка . При её нажатии должен изменяться Background.

Tags: c#, wpf

В Windows Form это выглядело все так:

```
this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.pejzazh_reka_zakat_37700;
```

Как указать из ресурсов в WPF чтобы по нажатию кнопки загружался Background.
Вроде все просто, ищу целый день как это меняется и не могу понять. СтэкОверфлоу излазил и там только изменяют все в XAML.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Смена картинки при нажатии кнопки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589439/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VisualStudio 2017 "Blank App"

XAML

```
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.258,-5" Click="Button_Click" Height="80" Width="80"/>
```

C# (Set the original image in the properties of the button: right-click -> Brush -> image)

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/timerg.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) };

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

В WPF это делается нет так. Вы не пользуетесь ресурсами (это создаёт нативные, Win32-ресурсы), а кладёте картинку в проект и выбираете Build Action = Resource.

Затем, вы пишете:

```
var assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
var resourcePath = "Images/PaysageRiverSunset.png";

var uri = new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/{assemblyName};component/{resourcePath}",
                  UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(uri);
control.Background = new ImageBrush(bitmap);
```

И да, в WPF всё намного легче делать через XAML. Не пытайтесь писать на WPF как на WinForms, будет тяжело и сложно.

---

Для сравнения, насколько проще было бы это сделать в XAML.

Вы кладёте в App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="PaysageRiverSunset" ImageSource="Images/PaysageRiverSunset.png"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

И в основном XAML

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource PaysageRiverSunset}" ... />
```

(или какой у вас там контрол).

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Просто в качестве тренировки решил переделать проэкт из WinForms в WPF. Из этого и буду тепреь исходить

Comment: Подскажите что такое контрол? Попробвоал ваш код для Шарпа - выдает кучу ошибок

Comment: @user6448834: Ну, то, у чего вы хотите установить `Background`. И не забудьте `using`'и!

Comment: Мне для чего в кодом представлении было все нужно.. ЧТобы задавать логикут использования. Чтобы при нажатии клавиши и проведении мышки открывалась картинка. Да кстати изменил как Вы сказали <Grid Background="{StaticResource PaysageRiverSunset}" ... /> но вес равно подсвечивает ошибки в XAML

Comment: @user6448834: Для этого правильным методом является отделение контента от представления и использование MVVM. Но и C#-код должен компилироваться и работать.

Comment: Я ещё забыл спросить  у Вас, а как встраивается этот Background  именно в Button? Именно в XAML. Как прописать, чтобы в баттоне был указан именно тот самый Background

Comment: @user6448834: `<Button Background="..."/>`, как-то так. В ответе есть пример с `Grid` вместо `Button`.