# Смена картинки при нажатии кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Хотел сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялась картинка. 
Хотел использовать код из *Windows Forms*:

```
private void Play_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mediaElement.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
    {
        mediaElement.Ctlcontrols.pause();
        Play_btn.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._11;
    }
    else
    {
        mediaElement.Ctlcontrols.play();
        Play_btn.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._112;
    }
}
```

Но в *WPF* так нельзя. Подскажите, как сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько подходов к решению вашей проблемы.
Рассмотрим один из них:

1.
Добавляете изображения в ресурсы (Удобно создать папку `Images`).

2.
В вашей `VM` создаете свойство `IsFirstImage`, которое будет отвечать за то, какая картинка будет отображена в вашем `Image`

```
    private bool isFirstImage;
    public bool IsFirstImage
    {
        get { return isFirstImage; }
        set { isFirstImage = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsFirstImage"); }
    }
```

3.
Создаете команду, которая отвечает за обработку нажатия кнопки:

```
    private ICommand clickCommand;
    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get { return clickCommand; }
        set { clickCommand = value; }
    }
```

4.
Остается написать функцию, которая будет изменять значение на противоположное:

```
    private void changeImage()
    {
        IsFirstImage = !IsFirstImage;
    }
```

5.
Конструктор VM:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        clickCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => changeImage());
    }
```

6.
Дальше описываете разметку:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="image">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFirstImage}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Images/Koala.jpg" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFirstImage}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Images/Penguins.jpg" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
            Content="Click" />
    <Image Grid.Row="1" 
           Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image}" />
</Grid>
```

Триггер данных позволяет установить отображаемую картинку в зависимости от значения вашего свойства.

Код для `RelayCommand` и реализацию интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged` не привожу, чтобы не загромождать ответ.

Результат получается следующим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

1. Используйте элемент управления Image.
2. Image должен получать новый Bitmap через свойство ImageSource.
3. Убедитесь, что изображения, которые вы используете - имели роль в проекте как Resource.